# Why doesn't room let me return Cursor from a DAO?

Tags: android, android-room

Following code throws the error:

```
e: error: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type). - android.database.Cursor

e: <path>.my_file.java:11: error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (android.database.Cursor).

public abstract java.lang.Object getAllWords(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

**Code:**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM my_table")
suspend fun getAllWords(): Cursor
```

Adding more information, the error went away when I removed `suspend` keyword. Am going ahead with this, but it would be great if someone knows why suspending `dao` methods of rooms are not able to return `Cursor`

Comment: the output can be null, does it work with `Cursor?` instead of `Cursor`

Comment: @Stachu, I tried that but still the same issue. Also FYI, I have added more details about the issue. All these issues go away as soon as I remove `Cursor` and put normal `List<Words>`